# Filtering Dataframe With isin Function

Tags: python, pandas, isin

I have a code that used to work for a large dataset in which I read and filter call center records. Suddenly, the code quit working with my latest Anaconda upgrade.

To test the code, I have created a super simple 3x2 dataframe to troubleshoot why the `isin` function isn't working anymore. I can't figure it out.

Here is what I tried:

This first step works well

```
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv')
```

The output for my new data frame is:

```
8003002419
8005555555
8003002419
```

Now I want all rows with a specific phone number to go into its own data frame.

```
mytfn = ['8003002419']
result_df = test_df[test_df['TFN'].isin(mytfn)]

result_df
```

The result comes up blank

Comment: You need to check the datatypes.  Pandas is probably converting your phone numbers to integers.  See if `mytfn=[8003002419]` works

Comment: It looks like those are getting read as ints, not strings. I've linked a question that explains how to keep them as strings. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and for tips, see [ask] and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: @TimRoberts Don't use integers for phone numbers. For example, if you had international numbers in the data set, the leading `0`s or `+` would get stripped, which would break them.

Comment: Thank you both. .info() does show my phone numbers were converted to integers. I made the change you suggested and it worked! Now I can follow the link to  how to keep them as strings.